# Send email on behalf of someone with their permission

Tags: email, smtp, spf

I have seen a few sites that send an email on behalf of a user, however when the email comes through it appears only as if its come from the user. For example contact forms on websites.

I am looking to do the same thing but obviously with the users permission. Is this possible to do in C# code or similar services available that won't go to the spam/junk folder?

Ideally the from/replyto email address should appear from the user and not get blocked i.e go through the right servers as long as I have their permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do this is if the domain they send through adds your domain's SPF to *their* SPF record, and possibly that they publish a DKIM record for which you hold the private key. In reality, there is no way this is going to happen for a contact form that allows arbitrary senders. Also, you're never going to get this to happen if the sender is using an email address from a service like gmail.

Thus the majority of contact forms that do this are simply doing it wrong – they are forging the from address and hoping they can get away with it, or that they simply don't know any better. Using a from address that you don't have permission for is simply forgery, and these days it will generally get dumped in spam or rejected outright – but that doesn't stop you from trying to do something so silly!

You mentioned the only workaround for this, which is a `reply-to` address. In this case you usually send from yourself, to yourself, but use the submitter's address as a reply-to, so that when you reply to the message, it goes to them. This does not require any special permission and is not forgery, so it generally works fine.

[The contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) uses this approach, and you should be able to get the idea whatever language you're using.

There are some practical issues with this approach. The main one is that mail programs often ignore the from *name* (not the address) in messages from addresses that they have seen before. This means that even if you put the submitter's name in the reply-to along with your own address (so it contains things like `Jane User <contactform@example.com>`, it will ignore it and use whatever name was *first* used with that address. This is annoying, but doesn't break anything.